# How do you retrieve json object from a searched website using getJSON or other method?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-search-api

How do I use .getJSON() to get JSON-encoded data from a website that is searched?

I create a Google Custom Search API for my website, and my goal is to retrieve the JSON file from the result.
Let's say when I typed "apple" in my Google Custom Search bar from my website, the result would look like what this picture shows

[image: Googel search result]

How do you retrieve the JSON object from this result? 
Such as the title, URL, and the description? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The result is not returned as JSON but HTML, you should inspect the HTML form (debugger) and how you can build your own functions that turn a html structure to a JSON structure!

Also there is lot of librairies that doing the conversion HTML to JSON. Here is one of them : https://github.com/Jxck/html2json ...

Comment: Thank you for answer, do you have any source that I can visit to learn how to turn a html structure to a JSON structure? Thank you

Comment: post updated. check the link below ..